# PySide2 QListView QTableView sync problem

Tags: python, model-view-controller, qtableview, qlistview, pyside2

It is python/PySide2 interface related problem, as much as I tried, I couldn't make it sync (QListView and QTableView).

I will try to simplify it, instead of explaining the whole complicated thing which is much bigger with full of forms stuff in QT...

Just imagine to have a data structure (I guess, model) like the following:

```
dict_of_dicts={
'dict1':{'k1':'v1', 'k2':'v2', 'k3':'v3'},
'dict2':{'k4':'v4'},
'dict3':{'k5':'v5', 'k6':'v6', 'k7':'v7'},
}
```

I would like to have a form (or dialog), with 2 parts:

1) In the left of the form, to have a QListView to visualize the following:

```
*dict1
------
dict2
-----
dict3
```

NOTES:

- The asterisk in the dict1 means that is selected.
- The hyphens are just to separate between rows.

2) In the right of the form, to have a QTableView showing the following:

```
k1 | v1
-------
k2 | v2
-------
k3 | v3
```

NOTES:

- The hyphens are just to separate between rows.
- The pipes, are just to represent the columns separation.
- Everytime you select the another element int the QListView, the QTableView must change to the one indicated by the original data structure.

I am sure it could be really easy for most of you guys, but I am just starting with UI stuff and MVC.

Comment: I recommend you go straight to the point, long speeches that do not contribute at all discourage you from helping.

Comment: I already told you that you should ask another question, please do it, you are only causing noise. In SO the questions should be as precise as possible, if you have many questions in a single post go against it. Remember that the button to create a post says *Ask Question*, does not say *Ask Question**s***

Comment: so sorry, i am really new here, don't wanna bother

Comment: It is also recommended that you review the SO guides: [tour], [ask] and [answer] so that you know the dynamics of the place. Finally you probably can not ask questions until some time passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a model with the tree structure where the dependency is seen, and in the case of the QListView it will show the root items and in the case of the QTableView it will show the leaves and it will have as rootIndex the selected QModelIndex of the QListView. For educational purposes I will show the model of the tree in a QTreeView.

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

dict_of_dicts={
    'dict1':{'k1':'v1', 'k2':'v2', 'k3':'v3'},
    'dict2':{'k4':'v4'},
    'dict3':{'k5':'v5', 'k6':'v6', 'k7':'v7'},
}

def create_model_from_dict(d, parent=None):
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 2, parent)
    for k, v in dict_of_dicts.items():
        it = QtGui.QStandardItem(k)
        model.appendRow(it)
        for k_, v_ in v.items():
            it.appendRow([QtGui.QStandardItem(k_), QtGui.QStandardItem(v_)])
    return model

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        model = create_model_from_dict(dict_of_dicts, self)

        self.tableview = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.tableview.setModel(model)

        self.listview = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.listview.setModel(model)
        self.listview.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.handleSelectionChanged)
        self.listview.selectionModel().select(model.index(0, 0), QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.Select)

        self.treeview = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.treeview.setModel(model)
        self.treeview.expandAll()

        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        hlay.addWidget(self.listview)
        hlay.addWidget(self.tableview)
        hlay.addWidget(self.treeview)

    @QtCore.Slot(QtCore.QItemSelection)
    def handleSelectionChanged(self, item):
        ixs = item.indexes()
        if ixs:
            self.tableview.setRootIndex(ixs[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]

[image]