# New feature for previous question PySide2 QListView and QTableView

Tags: python, qtableview, pyside2, qstandarditemmodel

The previous question was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54019582/add-feature-for-previous-question-pyside2-qlistview-and-qtableview).

EDITED TO PROVIDE INFO:

The model represents a dict of dicts, which they can inherit other dicts apart from key-value pairs:

```
dict_of_dicts={
'dict1':{'k1':'v1', 'k2':'v2', 'k3':'v3', 'EXISTING_DICT':'dict2'},
'dict2':{'k4':'v4'},
'dict3':{'k5':'v5', 'k6':'v6'},
}
```

being the qlistview:

```
*dict1
------
dict2
-----
dict3
```

and the qtableview with dict1 selected in the qlistview:

```
k1 | v1
-------
k2 | v2
-------
k3 | v3
-------
dict2
```

Is there a way to sort the model with first the inherited dicts on top, and then the dict elements?

```
dict2
-------
k1 | v1
-------
k2 | v2
-------
k3 | v3
```

And if we introduce new elements in the fly (I have way to introduce new elements in the interface), it get sorted no matter the order?

I was playing with QStandardItemModel sort and setSortRole(Qt.CheckStateRole)

Comment: you could explain with an example, I confuse your current explanation

Comment: what is *inherited dicts on top*?

Comment: new information were added!! Thanks eyllanesc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54021101/6622587) as a basis, It is necessary to use a `QSortFilterProxyModel` but we must use the role `QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000`, in addition we must modify the parts that I will point out with a comment:

```
# ...

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        model = create_model_from_dict(dict_of_dicts, self)

        self.tableview = TableView()
        self.proxy_model = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel() # <---
        self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(model) # <---
        self.proxy_model.setSortRole(QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000) # <---
        self.proxy_model.sort(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder) # <---
        self.tableview.setModel(self.proxy_model) # <---
        self.tableview.leftDoubleClicked.connect(self.handleSelectionChangedTV)

        # ...

    @QtCore.Slot(QtCore.QItemSelection)
    def handleSelectionChangedLV(self, item):
        ixs = item.indexes()
        if ixs:
            pix = self.proxy_model.mapFromSource(ixs[0]) # <---
            self.tableview.setRootIndex(pix) # <---
            model = self.tableview.model()
            self.tableview.clearSpans()
            for r in range(model.rowCount(self.tableview.rootIndex())):
                index = model.index(r, 0, self.tableview.rootIndex())
                if index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000):
                    self.tableview.setSpan(r, 0, 1, 2)

# ...
```

Comment: Amazing!! I didn't understand anything (didn't get still the role stuff since the beginning and now the proxymodel), but it is amazing!! Thanks!!

Comment: @eddy2k use `def getFirstSibling(self)
        ixs = self.tableview.selectedIndexes()
        if ixs:
            model_index = ixs[0]
            sibling_ix = model_index.sibling(model_index.row(), 1)
            return sibling_ix.data()`

Comment: @eddy2k remember that the QTableView model is no longer the QStandardItemModel but the QSortFilterProxyModel so the latter no longer has the itemFromIndex method, so instead of going the long way to get the QStandardItem you can access the text through the QModelIndex using the method data. read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html

Comment: Really useful! Thanks!!

Comment: Can you help me with this one sir? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54262785/text-styling-in-qtableview-with-pyside2